# Найти на графе путь, состоящий из ребер минимальной длины

Tags: графы, c++

Дан граф.
Нужно найти путь, состоящий из ребер минимальной длины. 
Но, как я понимаю, кратчайший путь не обязательно содержит рёбра минимальной длины(например, можно пройти по одному ребру до нужной вершины, а можно в обход по нескольким, но меньшего размера).
Какие существуют алгоритмы, чтобы найти нужный мне путь?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: надо найти от одной вершины до всех остальных?

Answer (score 1):

Вот то, что пришло в голову:

- Алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла
- Алгоритм Форда-Беллмана
- Алгоритм Дейкстры
- Алгоритм Дейкстры для разреженных графов
- Волновой алгоритм

Comment: лекция на ютубе Лекция 3: Алгоритмы и методы поиска кратчайшего пути в графе http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek721aS3CRE